# Combine rows based on key and also add the old joined data into a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

In python pandas, what is the easiest way with good readability to get from this dataframe A to dataframe B?

Dataframe A:

|  | key | streams | accidental |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 2.33349 | Major |
| 1 | A# | 3.0565 | Minor |
| 2 | B | 2.52871 | Major |
| 3 | C# | 3.02007 | Minor |
| 4 | D | 2.76289 | Major |
| 5 | D# | 2.57981 | Minor |
| 6 | E | 2.53651 | Major |
| 7 | F | 2.48089 | Major |
| 8 | F# | 2.58316 | Minor |
| 9 | G | 2.44892 | Major |
| 10 | G# | 2.7892 | Minor |

Dataframe B:

| key | major_streams | minor_streams |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2.33349 | 3.0565 |
| B | 2.52871 | nan |
| C | nan | 3.02007 |
| D | 2.76289 | 2.57981 |
| E | 2.53651 | nan |
| F | 2.48089 | 2.58316e |
| G | 2.44892 | 2.7892 |

My solution was to use a groupby aggregate to combine the streams and accidentals into lists. I also took out the '#" in the 'key' elements to be able to use a groupby.

```
df_agg = df_agg.groupby('key').agg({'streams': list, 'accidental' : list})
major,minor = streams_split(df_agg['streams'].to_list(), df_agg['accidental'].to_list())
test = pd.DataFrame({'major_streams': major, 'minor_streams': minor }, index =df_agg.index)
```

I then had a seperate helper function, streams_split, to manually seperate the 'streams' into major and minor python list and returned them. Then combined them again afterwards into a new dataframe using the new lists. Seems like bit of overkill and messy solution. Wondering if anyone has a better solution. Thanks for yalls time!

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

First, remove the '#' from the key column, then create a pivot table.

and I used `rename` function to change the column names to what you wanted.

```
(df.assign(key=df['key'].str.replace('#', ''))
   .pivot_table('streams', index='key', columns='accidental')
   .rename(lambda x: x.lower() + '_streams', axis=1))
```

output:

```
accidental  major_streams   minor_streams
key     
A           2.33349         3.05650
B           2.52871         NaN
C           NaN             3.02007
D           2.76289         2.57981
E           2.53651         NaN
F           2.48089         2.58316
G           2.44892         2.78920
```

---

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'key': ['A', 'A#', 'B', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#'], 
        'streams': [2.33349, 3.0565, 2.52871, 3.02007, 2.76289, 2.57981, 2.53651, 2.48089, 2.58316, 2.44892, 2.7892], 
        'accidental': ['Major', 'Minor', 'Major', 'Minor', 'Major', 'Minor', 'Major', 'Major', 'Minor', 'Major', 'Minor']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: If the initial dataframe A did not include the 'accidental' column, would the solution be similar? Thanks! That solution is so much simpler than what I was cooking up.

Comment: @JayNguyen Of course, the solution is different if there is no `accidental column`. It is not difficult to create a column corresponding to accidental **(groupby + cumcount)**, and you can refer to the [Q10 of following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way using `groupby` and some dataframe reshaping:

```
df.groupby([df['key'].str[0], df['accidental']])['streams']\
  .sum()\
  .unstack()\
  .rename_axis(None, axis=1)\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  key    Major    Minor
0   A  2.33349  3.05650
1   B  2.52871      NaN
2   C      NaN  3.02007
3   D  2.76289  2.57981
4   E  2.53651      NaN
5   F  2.48089  2.58316
6   G  2.44892  2.78920
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) job:

```
out = (pd.crosstab(df['key'].str.strip('#'), df['accidental'].str.lower(),
                   values=df['streams'], aggfunc='sum')
         .add_suffix('_streams')
         .reset_index().rename_axis(index=None, columns=None) # optional
      )
```

Output:

```
  key  major_streams  minor_streams
0   A        2.33349        3.05650
1   B        2.52871            NaN
2   C            NaN        3.02007
3   D        2.76289        2.57981
4   E        2.53651            NaN
5   F        2.48089        2.58316
6   G        2.44892        2.78920
```